# MySQL Problem: How to get the newest 4er group of this data

Tags: mysql

I have this Data in my tmp table. How can I get the latest (=newest) dataset where all 4 different stockplaces are in the set. (The set should be 4 lines only)

Here f.e. all from 2018-12-20  but I do not want to use a date in the query as the date is variable.

How can I do this? THANKS

```
     -- ----------------------------         
     -- Table structure for `OMENtmp`         
     -- ----------------------------         
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `OMENtmp`;         
     CREATE TABLE `OMENtmp` (         
       `id2` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,         
       `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',         
       `stockplace` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,         
       `MCCSIDate` date DEFAULT NULL,         
       PRIMARY KEY (`id2`)         
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;         

     -- ----------------------------         
     -- Records of OMENtmp         
     -- ----------------------------         
     INSERT INTO `OMENtmp` VALUES ('1', '1825711', '%', '2018-12-21');         
     INSERT INTO `OMENtmp` VALUES ('2', '1824590', 'HK+TW+AX+KS+T', '2018-12-21');         
     INSERT INTO `OMENtmp` VALUES ('3', '1825710', '%', '2018-12-20');         
     INSERT INTO `OMENtmp` VALUES ('4', '1825136', 'DE+VI+PA+AS+BR+MC+MI+L+VX', '2018-12-20');         
     INSERT INTO `OMENtmp` VALUES ('5', '1824589', 'HK+TW+AX+KS+T', '2018-12-20');         
     INSERT INTO `OMENtmp` VALUES ('6', '1824039', 'US', '2018-12-20');         
     INSERT INTO `OMENtmp` VALUES ('7', '1825709', '%', '2018-12-19');         
     INSERT INTO `OMENtmp` VALUES ('8', '1825135', 'DE+VI+PA+AS+BR+MC+MI+L+VX', '2018-12-19');         
     INSERT INTO `OMENtmp` VALUES ('9', '1824588', 'HK+TW+AX+KS+T', '2018-12-19');         
     INSERT INTO `OMENtmp` VALUES ('10', '1824038', 'US', '2018-12-19');
```

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu. I see you are a member of Stackoverflow as well. The question might be better suited over there. Be prepared to get asked about your attempts so far.

Comment: The problem is you don't have a properly normalized database design. The field `stockplace` contains multiple stockplaces separated by a `+` character. Now, when you want to pick rows by certain stockplaces, you need to split the `stockplace` at the separator and then deal with complicated split/join/concat statements. You better re-think the DB design and add two other tables for the stockplaces and the connection between the `id2` and those stockplaces.

Comment: @PerlDuck I believe there are actually four distinct values for the `stockplace` column, i.e. "HK+TW+AX+KS+T" counts as one. In which case this should be a matter of  doing `select stockplace, max(MCCSIDate) from OMENtmp group by stockplace`.

Comment: @jos yes but I need only the stockplaces from 20. as the max(Msccidate) = 21. and that is not complete by the for Regions

Comment: @PerlDuck no no not so complicated, stockplaces is just a string of re

Comment: It is a region of stockplaces, see my answer, complicated but this is was I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I made this:

```
    SELECT x.* from OMENtmp x join (select k.*,count(k.id2) as cc from OMENtmp k group by k.MCCSIDATE) p on p.MCCSIDate = x.MCCSIDAte where p.cc = 4 order  by MCCSIDAte desc limit 4 ;
```

This is the right answer, maybe it could be easier!